# Logging GET request URL's with Mechanize

Tags: ruby, http, mechanize

Is there a way to capture the various GET requests when Mechanize loads a given URL.  For example when watching the console in Firefox's dev tools you see various GET requests for loading the pages' media, etc...  I'm wondering if there is a way access and log that same info using Mechanize

Comment: Mechanize is not a browser, and doesn't behave like one. If you tell it to read a page, that is all it reads. It won't load images, CSS, or scripts referenced in that page, like a browser would. You can as easily print your URL requests to a file when you tell Mechanize to load a page.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable logging:

```
require "logger"
log = Logger.new "log.txt"
log.level = Logger::DEBUG

require "mechanize"
agent = Mechanize.new{ |a| a.log = log }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or proxy through Fiddler / Charles:

```
agent.set_proxy 'localhost', 8888
```